Flashing images with a locked bootloader
I am running a non-prodiction MediaTek device.
The device utilizes little kernel (lk & lk2) as it's bootloader. Which is locked. The device is permanently in fastboot.
How would I go about signing an image so the bootloader will accept it as 'signed'?
